# Cometchat Cloud in Expressionengine

Tags: ee

Does anybody have any idea about installing Cometchat Cloud in Expression engine as they are not showing it in their documentation packages?

Comment: I'm not sure this is an ee question.  It seems to me like cometchat cloud is a hosted solution that most likely just requires adding some html code to your site.  I couldn't find instructions at all without signing up.  It also states for ning right in the title of the product.  You probably need to provide more detail of what you have tried to get a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've used CometChat Cloud with ExpressionEngine and it works fine. You can signup at https://cloud.cometchat.com and then inform their team. They did the integration for me quite quickly.